# Make Simultaneous requests in karate feature file

Tags: karate

I have to test the rate-limiting functionality of my backend.
I need to make simultaneous requests (e.g: 5) and check if one of them has failed because of the rate-limiting settings in the backend.

Like something thats spawns 5 threads and each one does a request, or make 5 asynchrounous requests.

I have read about karate-gatling which does something similar but it seems it's for performance testing.

Is this possible?

Comment: several ways but as @peter thomas mentioned it might be overkill.

With karate junit parallel execution
you can copy paste examples via scenatio outline 5 times.
you can also do retry untill status reponse is not 200 (if 200 is success)

OR 
You can also use jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Karate is overkill for this, just use a Java [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) or something similar.